# How to insert 2 case when conditions into sum() function in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to do the following - insert 2 conditions to sum total_orders in SQL:

```
sum(case when A_voucher <> '' then 0 when A_voucher = '' then orders end) as total_orders
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to rectify this syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN A_voucher = '' THEN orders ELSE 0 END) AS total_orders
```

**Explanation**

It seems you are confusing the simple CASE expression syntax with the searched CASE expression syntax. See the [documentation for CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> - The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
> - The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

You want the searched CASE expression syntax:

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For your example you'll get away with one condition...

```
sum(case when A_voucher = '' then orders else 0 end) as total_orders
```

which is equivalent to the two condition version you asked for

```
sum(
    case 
        when A_voucher = '' then orders
        when A_voucher <> '' then 0 
    end) as total_orders
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `CASE` in this scenario, [filtered aggregations](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation) are more concise and easier to read:

```
sum(orders) FILTER (WHERE A_voucher = '')
```

Here's a complete working example:

```
presto> WITH t(orders, A_voucher) AS (
     ->     VALUES (1, ''), (2, 'x'), (4, ''), (8, 'y'))
     ->
     -> SELECT sum(orders) FILTER (WHERE A_voucher = '') AS total_orders
     -> FROM t
     -> ;

 total_orders
--------------
            5
```